# Dell PowerEdge IO and performance related problems

Tags: windows-server-2003, performance, dell

I have an Dell PowerEdge 830, but after installing a 4:th disk and while copying backup files to this new disk the overall performance of the server just plummet.

The system degrades to a point where it can not be accessed remotely over the network and basically freeze. But as soon as I cancel the copy operation things return to normal.

I can provide more information on the matter, but right now I'm thinking it's related to the bus speed, but why would it be so intense? Is there anything I can do to identify the problem, or has anyone run into a similar problem?

## Current disk configuration

- 3 disks connected to a **DELL CERC SATA 1.5/6ch RAID Controller**

  - Only two of these disks form a **RAID0** array
  - The 3rd disk seems to be unused
- The RAID array has 3 partitions, something called EISA configuration 31MB (don't know what this is), C: with 132GB and D: with 165GB
- 4th disk connected to a SATA port on the main board

Copying from the RAID array to the 4th disk kills server performance to a point where it's almost entirely unresponsive.

Comment: If you're running several disks off the same cable, that's probably the issue right there. How is the hardware plugged in?

Comment: 3 disks are connected to a RAID controller, (2 of those make out a RAID array, 1 of those disk seem to be unused), the 4:th disk is connected on it's own SATA0 port directly on the main board.

Comment: That is peculiar. Perhaps you're saturating the channel, but I've never actually heard of that from SATA drives. I'm giving you +1 for the question. This is interesting.

Comment: More specs please! RAID controller, what types are the other 3 drives (SAS, SATA), and what type of RAID (0,1,5, etc), how are your containers set up, and what OS are you running (yes this might make a difference).

Comment: I've put the Windows-Server-2003 tag on the question, thus, the server is running Windows Serer 2003. I'm not sure if it's an RAID0 or RAID1 configuration, I'm leaning towards a RAID0 configuration with two 160GB SCSI disk drives

Comment: Reboot and ask the CERC what the disk configuration is?  I assume it's like the PERC in that it has a configuration screen you can get at before booting.

Also, do you have a DRAC in there?  If so, what does it say about system state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the integrated s-ata isn't running in compatibility mode, and that you have updated drivers for the integrated controller.

Comment: I'm gonna try this out, haven't been able to yet but I'm quite sure I did set the ATA-compatibility mode. It looked like that was the only option that would enable the mainboard SATA ports. I'll have to check back to confirm. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

CERC == "Cost Effective Raid Controller" which I'm learning means something along the lines of "driver-based software RAID implementation."

Are you sure it's a RAID0?  Given the sizes you mention of your partitions, you have 297GB of usable space.  Dell didn't ship that with 300GB SATA disks, at least according to [this](http://www.dell.com/downloads/global/products/pedge/en/830_specs.pdf).  I'm going to bet that you have 3 160GB SATA disks in a RAID5 with one disk failed.  A failed drive in a RAID5 array with a "driver-based software RAID implementation" would peg the CPU on your machine to the point of pain during reads.

I bet if you tried the same file transfer to remote disks you'll have the same performance problems.

-Dave

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem as well. In general I noticed that the performance of Dell's SAS controller (i5 or something like that) is very bad. That's why I switched to regular SATA disks which are classes faster than anything attached to Dell's controller...

Comment: Do you have any benchmarks you'd like to share? Just curious.

Comment: In my experience the PERC5i performs quite well.

Comment: PERC5i/6i is slower than simple SATA with no RAID? You are terribly wrong here. 

The only thing they are slow is is during POST/boot, because the controller has to run a sequence which detects the disk WWNs, and checks them for RAID configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Would you mind to tell the FW version of the controller?

If you don't have the latest please upgrade and confirm the problem:

http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/download.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=gen&releaseid=R155588&SystemID=WRK_PNT_P4_670&servicetag=&os=WXPX&osl=en&deviceid=5646&devlib=0&typecnt=0&vercnt=4&catid=&impid=&formatcnt=4&libid=41&typeid=-1&dateid=-1&formatid=-1&fileid=207606

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the 2 storage controllers are sharing IRQs.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a requirement, but I would lean towards only using 1 raid controller per disk array. if you want to use another sata stand alone disk, plug it into the mobo, or get another drive controller. I would only have my raid controller control my raid array. I bet your problems would disappear after you moved the stand alone disk off the raid controller.